# Generate iMovie Edit Decision List from Java?

Tags: java, macos, video, video-editing

Is there any known way to generate an iMovie project (or more specifically, an edit decision list -- a sequence of video files and in/out points) from outside of iMovie?  I would like to create this list externally, and somehow import it into current-generation iMovie.  The iMovie file format seems to be an Apple Binary PList, but it isn't documented anywhere (and reverse-engineering it violates the terms of use, I believe).

Any thoughts?

Alternatively, can anyone suggest a similar low-cost/consumer-friendly editing app that runs on OS X, and does support EDL import?

Comment: Retagged your ques. I am not sure about the SDK version though, change it if you have any preferences

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I don't think iMovie was designed or meant for batch editing of files. I believe that is what you are after?

I have iMovie myself but I haven't done any application development on the iDevices. Your best bet would be to somehow trigger the UI elements through an another application and you script the triggering. But I am not even sure if that is possible, perhaps some app developers on iphone can help you out here..

Comment: Re-retagged (see explanation of edit too) since I'm working with desktop OS X, not iOS.